# How to implement the View or Download functionality like gmail in PHP?

Tags: php, view, download

If you click view,you'll open that file in browser,

while download will pop up a dialog to save that file on your disk.

Answer (score 1):

Download vs View is controled by `content-disposition` header. Just add header below and you will get Save File dialog box.

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf
```

Comment: What's the header for download and view respectively?

Comment: By default you will get view. If you will add header with name "content-disposition" and value "attachment; filename=test.pdf" you will get download.

Comment: What about the `content-type`?

Comment: `content-type` is about MIME type of the resource, for example JPEG images are `image\jpeg`. More on the topic - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type